# Python Conditional "With" Lock Design

Tags: python, locking, with-statement

I am trying to do some shared locking using with statements

```
def someMethod(self, hasLock = False):
     with self.my_lock:
         self.somethingElse(hasLock=True)


def somethingElse(self, hasLock = False):
    #I want this to be conditional...
    with self.my_lock:
          print 'i hate hello worlds"
```

That make sense?  I basically only want to do the with if I don't already have the lock.

On top of being able to accomplish this, is it a bad design? Should I just acquire/release myself?

Comment: Not any more, i am going to use RLock

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just use a `threading.RLock` which is re-entrant meaning it can be acquired multiple times by the same thread.

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#rlock-objects

For clarity, the `RLock` is used in the `with` statements, just like in your sample code:

```
lock = threading.RLock()

def func1():
    with lock:
        func2()

def func2():
    with lock: # this does not block even though the lock is acquired already
        print 'hello world'
```

As far as whether or not this is bad design, we'd need more context. Why both of the functions need to acquire the lock? When is `func2` called by something other than `func1`?

Comment: @Nix “All of the objects provided by this module that have acquire() and release() methods can be used as context managers for a with statement.”

Comment: Keep in mind that you will have to keep track of how many times lock has been acquired as release will not fully unlock the lock until the count reaches 0.

Answer (score 8):

The Python `or` is [short circuiting](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions) so you can make the locking conditional:

```
def somethingElse(self, hasLock = False):
    #I want this to be conditional...
    with hasLock or self.my_lock:
          print 'i hate hello worlds'
```

Unfortunately it's not quite that easy, because a boolean isn't a valid return from a `with` statement. You'll need to create a class with the `__enter__` and `__exit__` to wrap the boolean `True` value.

Here's one possible implementation that I haven't tested.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def withTrue():
    yield True

def withbool(condition):
    if condition:
        return withTrue()
    return False

def somethingElse(self, hasLock = False):
    with withbool(hasLock) or self.my_lock():
          print 'i hate hello worlds'
```

This is a lot of boilerplate for something so simple, so the RLock solution looks like a winner. This solution might be useful in a different context though.

Comment: This would be a great time to use [contextmanager](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Comment: I think this would work, but RLock does what i need out of the box.  Thanks.

Comment: @jleedev, thanks, I forgot about contextmanager. Unfortunately I don't think it would work in this context since you only want to wrap the True value, not the False.

Comment: Better use https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext

Answer (score 2):

Using with statement is better than just `acquire()` and `release()` functions. This way, if an error occurs, the locks will be released.

Comment: Can you do with conditionally?

Comment: You can't do conditional statements, but some objects support assignment via with statement. For example `with open("x.txt") as f: print f.read()`

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
def someMethod(self):
     with self.my_lock:
         self.somethingNoLock()

def somethingElse(self):
    with self.my_lock:
         self.somethingNoLock()

def somethingNoLock(self):
    print 'i hate hello worlds"
```

Note that while `someMethod` and `somethingElse` are identical in my solution, in general they would be different. You could put another wrapper around `somethingNoLock` so that the lock acquisition and release is not repeated multiple times.

This is far simpler and straightforward. Just because the re-entrant lock hammer is available, I wouldn't recommend using it when there is a more straightforward, less fragile way to nail it.

The more specific criticism of rlock is that the line that creates the re-entrant lock is far away from the code that is acquiring the lock in a re-entrant way. This is slightly fragile if someone say coalesces the re-entrant lock with another lock that is not re-entrant or otherwise changes the line that creates the lock.

Answer (score 1):

The `with` statement is a great way to implement locking, as locking is a perfect resource acquisition pattern. Though your current example won't work. You'll need an `if` statement around the `with` statement within `somethingElse()`.