# Other builtin or practical examples of python `with` statement usage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement, conceptual, contextmanager

Does anyone have a real world example outside of python's file object implementation of an `__enter__` and `__exit__` use case? Preferably your own, since what I'm trying to achieve is a better way to conceptualize the cases where it would be used.

I've already read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

And, [here's a link to the python documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are *many* uses. Just in the standard library we have:

- `sqlite3`; using the [connection as a context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) translates to committing or aborting the transaction.
- `unittest`; using [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) as a context manager lets you assert an exception is raised, then test aspects of the exception.
- `decimal`; [`localcontext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) manages decimal number precision, rounding, and other aspects.
- `threading` objects such as locks, semaphores and conditions are [context managers too](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement); letting you obtain a lock for a set of statements, etc.
- the `warnings` module gives you a [context manager to temporarily catch warnings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings).
- many libraries offer closing behaviour, just like the default file object. These include the [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) and the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) modules.
- Python's own [`test.test_support` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html) uses several context managers, to check for specific warnings, capture `stdout`, ignore specific exceptions and temporarily set environment variables.

Any time you want to detect when a block of code starts and / or ends, you want to use a context manager. Where before you'd use `try:` with a `finally:` suite to guarantee a cleanup, use a context manager instead.

Answer (score 4):

I've found it useful to have a `contextmanager` version of `os.chdir()`: on exit it `chdir()`s back to the original directory.

This allows you to emulate a common (Bourne) shell-scripting pattern:

```
(
cd <some dir>
<do stuff>
)
```

I.e. you change to a new dir `<some dir>` inside a subshell (the `(` `)`) so that you are sure to return to your original dir, even if the `<do stuff>` causes an error.

Compare the context manager and vanilla versions in Python.  Vanilla:

```
original_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(<some dir>)
try:
    <do stuff>
finally:
    os.chdir(original_dir)
```

Using a context manager:

```
with os.chdir(<some dir>):
    <do stuff>
```

The latter is much nicer!

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this example and how spelled out it is. Really good example for explaining the concept.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few examples on the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WithStatement).

The canonical answer is locks:

```
with (acquire some mutex):
    # do stuff with mutex
```

[Here's a Stack Overflow question and answer involving locks and the `with` statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185568/python-conditional-with-lock-design)