# Python: Idiom for interleaved lock acquisition

Tags: python, python-multithreading, idioms, with-statement

Suppose I need to do the following:

```
global_lock.acquire()
local_lock = threading.Lock()
local_lock.acquire()
register_local_lock(local_lock, some_associated_data)
global_lock.release()
do_some_work()
local_lock.release()
```

Q: How can I achieve the same thing using `with` statement?

P.S. In my application, there actually exist a workaround that separates the two lock acquisition. However, I think there could be senarios where the two lock acquisition must stay interleaved, so I'm still posting, with an additional question:

Q: Can all interleaved lock acquisition be eliminated by refactoring?

Comment: This example could use some improvement. Are you sharing `local_lock` between threads? As you wrote this code it's not clear `local_lock` is necessary. Also, is it necessary to hold `global_lock` while calling `register_local_lock `? If so, please make it clear that it is in your question.

Comment: @Alex  I did get rid of interleaved lock acquisition in my application. I just wander if there are situations where no suitable workaround exists.

Answer (score 0):

Q2:  Yes, all interleaving can be eliminated.  See any text on operating systems.  This goes back to Per Brink Hansen's seminal work and the "banker's problem".  If you mis-handle interleaved lock acquisition in any way, you can leave your system deadlocked.

In this case, it looks to me as if the only protection global_lock gives is where you access the handle to threading.lock.  Is this actually necessary?  Note that local_lock protects the rest of the critical region.

Q1: See [Python Conditional  "With" Lock Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185568/python-conditional-with-lock-design)

Comment: In my example there is no risk of deadlock, so banker's algorithm is not likely to be helpful. Additionally, I want to eliminate this situation in python code, so that `with` statement can be used instead of `acquire()` `release()`. Sorry I didn't make it clear in my question.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you have no deadlock danger.  Did the link for Q1 solve the other question for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is a different question, in which there is only one lock. For my question, because the locked period of the two locks interleaves, their `with` statement scope must also interleave, which is impossible in python grammar.

Comment: I see.  No, if the scope overlaps, then you cannot do this with *two* "with" statements.  You would have to eliminate the interleave and nest the "with" statements.